# Iteratively plot columns and reset ylab dynamically using ggplot2

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

Given dataframes df1 and df2 as follows:

**df1:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 3L), .Label = c("2021/1/31", "2021/2/1", "2021/2/10", 
"2021/2/2", "2021/2/3", "2021/2/4", "2021/2/5", "2021/2/6", "2021/2/7", 
"2021/2/8", "2021/2/9"), class = "factor"), value1 = c(9.76, 
9.76, 9.88, 9.31, 9.71, 9.56, 9.27, 9.22, 9.21, 9.08, 8.78), 
    value2 = c(6.84, 6.88, 6.95, 6.65, 6.94, 6.85, 6.66, 6.66, 
    6.6, 6.5, 6.25), value3 = c(6.33, 6.21, 6.31, 6.2, 6.56, 
    6.36, 6.36, 6.25, 6.1, 6.02, 5.76), value4 = c(10.68, 10.91, 
    11, 10.49, 10.8, 10.5, 10.2, 9.85, 10.03, 9.8, 9.51), value5 = c(7.77, 
    7.84, 7.83, 7.44, 7.83, 7.77, 7.6, 7.46, 7.46, 7.39, 7.29
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

**df2:**

```
df2 <- structure(list(type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("pct_change", 
"price", "quantity"), class = "factor"), columns = structure(1:5, .Label = c("value1", 
"value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"), class = "factor"), unit = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "%", "$"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

With code below, I'm able to loop all columns based `df2`, which means for each columns, if their types are identical, then plot them on same plot and finally save them with name of type.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)
df1.m <- melt(df1, id = "date")  # convert to long format
# add "type" variable to df1.m
df1.m2 = merge(df1.m, df2, by.x = "variable", by.y = "columns")

# for each "type", filter the data to that type, plot, and save    
for(my_type in unique(df1.m2$type)) {
  g <- ggplot(data = df1.m2[df1.m2$type == my_type,],
       aes(x=date, y = value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 1) 
  print(g)
  # ggsave(paste0(my_type,".png"))
}
```

Now I hope to reset `ylab()` for each plot, which means if its type is identical, then set its `ylab()` using `unit` from `df2`.

I try code below, but it's not working:

```
for(my_type in unique(df1.m2$type)) 
  for (my_unit in unique(df1.m2$unit)){
  g <- ggplot(data = df1.m2[df1.m2$type == my_type,],
       aes(x=date, y = value, colour=variable)) +
    ylab(my_unit) +
  geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 1) 
  print(g)
  # ggsave(paste0(my_type,".png"))
}
```

How could I achieve that based on code above? Sincere thanks at advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you tried with the nested `for`. As far as I get it you could achieve your desired result by using the `unique(unit)` of your filtered dataset as the label for `y` scale:

```r
library(ggplot2)
 
for(my_type in unique(df1.m2$type)) {
  d <- df1.m2[df1.m2$type == my_type,]
  g <- ggplot(data = d,
              aes(x=date, y = value, colour=variable)) +
    geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 1) +
    labs(y = unique(d$unit))
  print(g)
}
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? In general that means that you try to use a function as a dataframe. If I should guess I would say that your renamed the dataframe I called `d` by `df` but missed to replace it in all code lines.

Comment: Yes, I've made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach which avoids looping through the dataframe altogether.

1. Convert `df1` to long format and rename `name` to `columns`
2. Join to `df2` on `columns`
3. Mutate column `type` to include the units
4. Plot value versus date, color by `columns` and facet by `type`
5. Make some theme adjustments to display type and units on each facet axis

   ```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(dplyr)
   library(tidyr)

   df1 %>% 
     pivot_longer(2:6, 
                  names_to = "columns") %>% 
     left_join(df2) %>% 
     mutate(type = paste(type, unit)) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(date, value)) + 
     geom_line(aes(color = columns, 
                   group = columns)) + 
     facet_grid(type ~ ., 
                switch = 'y', 
                scales = "free_y") +
     theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
     strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'),
     strip.placement = 'outside',
     strip.text.y = element_text(angle=180))
   ```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is pretty cool alternative approach, I'll test it.

Comment: If I have many columns, it will generate all subplots in one plot, right?

Comment: Yes there will be as many facets as there are values for `type` - so it may not be suitable if there are too many. In that case I would still pivot, join and mutate, but then `filter` by type to generate separate plots.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(my_type in unique(df1.m2$type)) {
  
  g <- ggplot(
      data = df1.m2[type == my_type],
      aes(x=date, y = value, colour=variable)
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) {
      if(my_type == "price") { 
        paste("$", x)
      } else if(my_type == "pct_change") {
        paste(x, "%")
      } else {
        x
      }
    }) +
    geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 1) 
    print(g)
  # ggsave(paste0(my_type,".png"))
}
```

Or use instead of the if else a switch

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) {
  switch(my_type, "price" = paste("$", x), "pct_change" = paste(x, "%"), x)  
})
```

[image]
[image]
[image]